# How to find and replace all cells with an attribute in pandas/python

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, salesforce, data-cleaning

I cant find any info specific to finding attribute within cells of a df. Below is a sample of the data without the real names/orgs but otherwise you can see its quite a mess. I am new to data cleaning and I need to find a way to select all 'cells' with a certain attribute in the df. I need to keep the data so to replace or drop them is not an option I dont think. 
I am volunteering with a museum to help clean up their SalesForce account and for years they have been taking note of every donation (among other things) in a column called 'Important Notes'. I exported all the data to an .xls file and with a jupyter notebook using pandas I reduced the df to just 3 columns: the index, org name, and the 'important notes' column. Because this 'Important Notes' column has info that needs to be kept my plan is to try and filter all cells in the column WITHOUT a '$' and then change them all to Null as a place holder and then clean the rest to make them uniform entries to add up into a new total donations column. My plan is to do this then import it back into SF then apply a function to add the donations and give a running total of the amount a specific organization or donor has contributed. 
If anyone could offer possible solutions or point me in a helpful direction it would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Hoping to eventually have a column like this:

[image]

Comment: you could just add a sample df with dummy data and show your desired output.

Comment: the fact you are asking to use pandas, means you are already in the right direction. this question lacks any sample data that recreates your issue, type it 5,10 rows in excel and paste it here as it is. (no need to format) unless you provide your sample data and a output we will have to vote for this q to be closed.

Comment: Code/data should be included as text in the post itself, not in images.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very cryptic, but if you want to filter the rows that do not contain a '$'. You can do this:

```
import pandas as pd

# Dummy df
columns = ['org_name', 'important_notes']
data = [
    ['secret org', 'very shady'],
    ['very secret org', '$100000']
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
df
```

Output:

```
     org_name         important_notes
0   secret org         very shady
1   very secret org    $100000
```

df without rows containing the dollar sign.

```
df_no_dollars = df[~df['important_notes'].str.contains("\$")]
df_no_dollars
```

Output:

```
     org_name   important_notes
0   secret org  very shady
```